# How to get all root children in Firebase using TypeScript and Ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have this Firebase database:

[image]

and I need to get all uids(children) of alii-b9d94. But the problem is: when I get it as an object, I can't access the object to get the values from it.

This what I am able to get it but I can't access it:
[image]

ts code:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    import firebase from 'firebase';

    import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth';
    import { InfoService } from '../../services/info';


   @IonicPage()
   @Component({
selector: 'page-dash',
templateUrl: 'dash.html',
})

 export class DashPage {


     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          private infoService: InfoService,
          private authService: AuthService) {

            firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snap) => {

            let rootVals = snap.val();
            let uids : string[] = [];

          /* I am trying to access this by this code but not working :(
   I knew the problem with .this but Is there any other way i can through it 
            retrieve every child in a single variable */

            console.log(rootVals.this.uids); 


            console.log("rootVals");
            console.log(rootVals);

          } );
}

}
```

How to get and store each child in a single variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let uids = [];
let rootVals = [];

firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snap) => {
    let result = snap.value();
    for(let k in result){
     uids.push(k);
     rootVals.push(result[k]);
    }
});
```

"snap.value()" has both key and value object together , so using for loop like this, you can get object key and value separately.

when each time for loop runs , "k" gives object key. so you can get all keys of each object. Also "result[k]" gives the value object.

if you need to get key and value together, you can make your own json object and push into array

```
let keys_values = []
firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snap) => {
    let result = snap.value();
    for(let k in result){
      keys_values.push({
        key : k,
        values : result[k]
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it's always a good idea to include an explanation of what the code is doing and how it solves the issue.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I have edited the code. Thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 0):

To get only the keys(uids), try this:

```
firebase.database().ref().on('value', (snap) => {
snap.forEach(child => {
let keys=snap.key;
  });
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key